Remove legend from plotly volume plot
I have to remove the legend from the plotly volume plot. The only reason for doing this is I am making a poster where I have bunch of similar figures and I will only keep one figure with legend and remove others to save some space. I have wasted more than two hours but could not figure that out. Below is a sample code:
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import numpy as np

# Sample data
x, y, z = np.mgrid[0:1:10j, 0:1:10j, 0:1:10j]
values = np.sin(x**2 + y**2 + z**2)

# Create the figure
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=1, specs=[[{'type': 'scene'}]], subplot_titles=['Sample Volume Plot'])

# Add the volume trace
fig.add_trace(go.Volume(
    x=x.flatten(), y=y.flatten(), z=z.flatten(),
    value=values.flatten(),
    isomin=0, isomax=1, opacity=0.1, surface_count=15, colorscale='Inferno'
), row=1, col=1)

# Update layout to remove the legend
fig.update_layout(
    title="Sample Volume Plot",
    height=650, width=900,
    title_x=0.5,
    showlegend=False  # Not working
)

# Show the plot
fig.show()


Thank you for great help. Stackoverflow is kind of my last hope.

If you simply do not want to display the color scale, add showscale=False. I have not tested this on a subplot, but I also believe it is possible by setting the color scale to show or hide in each graphing.
# Add the volume trace
fig.add_trace(go.Volume(
    x=x.flatten(), y=y.flatten(), z=z.flatten(),
    value=values.flatten(),
    isomin=0,
    isomax=1,
    opacity=0.1,
    surface_count=15,
    colorscale='Inferno',
    showscale=False, #update 
), row=1, col=1)



Thank you for great great help @r-beginners.  I am highly thankful to your for this great and kind help.
